# How to set wired interface on Monitor Mode?

Tags: monitoring, wireshark

I could set my Wireless connection on Monitor Mode. And i could capture packets using wireshark. But how do i set my wired connection on monitor mode so that i can capture wired traffic too on wireshark? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

> But how do i set my wired connection on monitor mode

You don't.  Monitor mode is a Wi-Fi concept that doesn't apply to wired networks.

> so that i can capture wired traffic too on wireshark?

On a wired network, if you want to capture traffic that's not being sent to or from your machine, you need to put the adapter into promiscuous mode; Wireshark (and tcpdump) *default* to doing so, so you'd have to do something special *not* to put the adapter into promiscuous mode.

*However*, most Ethernet networks are switched, and, on a switched Ethernet,  it's not sufficient to turn on promiscuous mode; [you also have to arrange that the switch send you other hosts' traffic](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet#Switched_Ethernet).

Answer (score 0):

Very tough  , untill u do something with ur ehernet cable and router to listen to the air packets broadcasted by access point/another router in range , the conept of monitor mode seems to be compatible with the case where your nic is capable of listening to all broadcasting of destination Mac address ND its associated packet. Basically ,  ur router seems to be handling a private network of URS.. if you want to listen to the packets broadcasted for a Mac addresses under ur own private network via Ethernet cable , then , it would only be possible , if ur own machine nic could be set to monitoring mode ...so when ur router broadcast data to ur local private network , ur machine could consume that , but hold on  ... The packet will be consumed already ND forward ing of braodcast could be stopped ,if another machine before you  is an expected reliever of that packet as it's mac match with packet Mac ,  on wifi side , the router throws the packet in the air , ND devices that come into the range of that packet could recieve it considering the device nic should be developed with intention of listening to monitor mode of each packet broadcasted and for connected wires , router does not need to throw packets in the air , as recieve is connected to router via Ethernet cable ...so router sends that data in wired direction devices

Comment: How does this answer differ from the previous up voted answer?